How many US Senators are needed to agree to a chamber recess?
Looking for how many or what percentage of US Senators are needed to agree to a chamber recess?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about law. Senate sets and changes its rules with a simple majority.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A majority of those in the chamber
A recess motion is carried by a simple majority. Under the current rules, it is the only motion that can be considered in the absence of a quorum.
